# arraylist.get() issue with no syntax issues

Tags: java

The following code compiles just fine -

```
import java.util.*;
public class Aint
{
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

    public Aint()
    {
        nums.add(3);
        nums.add(5);
    }

    public void calcSum()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i <= nums.size(); i++){
            sum += nums.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call the method I get the error -

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2, Size 2 (in java.util.ArrayList)

I'm completely clueless.

Sorry about this, I'm new.

Comment: "compiles fine" doesn't matter when your logic is off. Don't use `<=` in your for loop, same as thousands of similar quesitons.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
for(int i = 0;i <= nums.size(); i++){
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
```

as the arrayList is zero based